# File Input Passing String To Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload files to my laravel site using `<input type="file">` yet it seems to be passing a string to the controller. I have this test to see if its a file yet I keep getting `File not ok`.

```
        if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
            dd('File ok');
        }
        dd('File not ok');
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Normally you would write that as `if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
            dd('File ok');
        } else {
        dd('File not ok'); }`

Comment: You need a name on your input

Comment: @Devon it has a name. Sorry forgot to include it in the example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this may be you're not setting your form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, it should be like this

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Or maybe, your input has no name attribute like

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Comment: I think it it the missing part of it was name Attribute laravel wont return a string

Comment: The missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` did the trick. Thanks